# Adding new fermions to a two-dimensional space

Tags: mesoscopic-physics

Suppose we have a two-dimensional space where we can seat electrons. Now, is it so that even before we start adding electrons the single electron energy levels already exist and as soon as we begin adding electrons, they start occupying the already existing levels. Does the spacing between the levels changes after each added electron? When we add electrons every second electron enters a higher energy level so does that mean if we know the height, that is the wave vector of the last entered electron, we can calculate the density? Each new electron enters a higher energy level, that means higher energy would be needed to add each new electron, so can we determine the electron density after each added electron if we know the energy which was required to add the extra electron? In the case of fermi gas, we do not consider the electronic repulsion between the electrons, so the higher and higher energies required to enter each new electron is due to which classical counterpart? The energy required to enter each new electron will also increase due to Coulomb repulsion. So, if we want to calculate the total energy needed to add each new electron would we have to include both the factors, the Pauli exclusion principle, and the Coulomb repulsion?
Every second electron in the two-dimensional space has a different energy, so what energies do they actually differ in? Is this kinetic energy? Suppose we want to introduce a new electron then is it so that energy of the newly added electron should be precisely equal to the new Fermi energy? What is the physical process by which we add the electron? What will happen to the electron which we are trying to add if the added electron does not have an energy equal to the new Fermi energy? If we decide to add new electron with precisely the new Fermi energy should we also include the effect of Coulomb repulsion if we want to introduce the electron with the exact energy?
No two electrons can occupy the same energy level if they have the same spin. What does that actually mean? Does that imply if we have two electrons one at each end, with the same spin, both of them can not have the same kinetic energy? If, quantum mechanically, we consider them kept inside a potential well 
what should be the length of the boundaries?